# Status updates at regular intervals

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, updates

How can I update status at regular intervals? For example when user wrote a comment, time show below comment like;

```
  Some comment
     1 minute ago
```

After 1 hour I want to it like;

```
  Some comment
    1 hour ago
```

Can I do this with PHP & MySQL?

Comment: Yes, you can...with the help of ajax

Comment: @Dr.Dan: The OP already tagged the question [tag:ajax]... I think he may have been looking for more guidance than that.  Besides which, I don't see ajax as being necessary for this (merely holding the comment time in JavaScript and firing events from there should suffice - no asynchronous calls necessary, unless new comments also need appear on the page).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're after is called 'humanizing' the time difference

If you want to do this with javascript so you don't need to do ajax to reload the value over and over check out:
http://momentjs.com/docs/

If you want to do this with PHP, check out the following snippet:
https://gist.github.com/1053741

Answer (score 0):

You can work with saving the current_timestamp in your mysql-db when the user writes a comment. Later you can show that query and manipulate it with php-time functions (you got the time when the user posted a command, and you got the current time, do the math)

Answer (score 0):

You can look this light weight jquery library for time manipulation.

http://momentjs.com/